# Most efficient way of adding/removing a character to beginning of string?

Tags: c#, string, performance, concatenation

I was doing a small 'scalable' C# MVC project, with quite a bit of read/write to a database.

From this, I would need to add/remove the first letter of  the input string.

---

**'Removing'** the first character is quite easy (using a Substring method) - using something like:

```
String test = "HHello world";
test = test.Substring(1,test.Length-1);
```

**'Adding'** a character efficiently seems to be messy/awkward:

```
String test = "ello World";
test = "H" + test;
```

Seeing as this will be done for a lot of records, would this be be the most efficient way of doing these operations?

I am also testing if a string starts with the letter 'T' by using, and adding 'T' if it doesn't by:

```
String test = "Hello World";
if(test[0]!='T')
{
    test = "T" + test;
}
```

and would like to know if this would be suitable for this

Comment: Will you have to append a character to several different records or to the same string?

Comment: You can use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if it is small project you can omit thinking about perfect efficiency.

Comment: Stringbuilder for string manipulation becomes more efficient the more it is used for a given string, i.e. over 10,000 times and it is much more efficient than using your method.

Comment: It would depend on what the field's first character would be, and so may or may not be applied. @Anton, currently this project is quite small, but will have quite large tables over time (due to the nature of the table)

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx String.Compare for comparisons. Also consider String.Replace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra thanks for the link, but I wouldn't be comparing one string to another - more one string starting with a specific char?

Comment: @MrCoder The fact that you use double quotes "T" makes T a string, 'T' would be a char. String.Compare has useful options like ignore case, and culture options too.

Comment: cheers for the tip Paul :)

Comment: @MrCoder You could also use test.Chars(0) to get the first character of your string, instead of using substring and length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are equally efficient I think since both require a new `string` to be initialized, since `string` is immutable.

When doing this on the same string multiple times, a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) might come in handy when adding. That will increase performance over adding.

You could also opt to move this operation to the database side if possible. That might increase performance too.

Comment: it would be multiple strings (it would read from db with possible T - i want to remove that, doStuff(), insert new records with T (after checking if they have T also). So the specific string would only be edited once, if at all. Would stringbuilder still be the way forward?

Comment: It depends on the number of operations on a `string`. I am not sure what the point is where `StringBuilder` outweighs `string`. Simple operations like this are much more efficient in the database.

Comment: 0-2 times? and so leave it as a String rather than StringBuilder (sorry I don't know how to add codeblocks within comments)

Comment: I think the range is much higher since it involves creating the actual `StringBuilder` in memory, stack operations, etc. Also depends on the length of the string. I usually start when I know the number of operations exceed 10-20 on medium length strings.

Answer (score 6):

If you have several records and to each of the several records field you need to append a character at the beginning, you can use `String.Insert` with an index of 0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string yourString = yourString.Insert( 0, "C" );
```

This will pretty much do the same of what you wrote in your original post, but since it seems you prefer to use a Method and not an operator...

If you have to append a character several times, to a single string, then you're better using a `StringBuilder` http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would prefer an operator instead of a method, it's just not all input strings will need to be edited (unlike my spelling, it seems :P), and so I use methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

For removing I would use the remove command as this doesn't require to know the length of the string:

```
test = test.Remove(0, 1);
```

You could also treat the string as an array for the Add and use

```
test = test.Insert(0, "H");
```

If you are always removing and then adding a character you can treat the string as an array again and just replace the character.

```
test = (test.ToCharArray()[0] = 'H').ToString();
```

When doing lots of operations to the same string I would use a `StringBuilder` though, more expensive to create but faster operations on the string.

Comment: Strings are immutable, cant do that `test[0] = "H"`

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that, could still be treated as a char array using the ToCharArray() method although a little more expensive `str = (str.ToCharArray()[0] = 'H').ToString();`

Comment: That means you are creating an additional character array. It won't be more efficient like this.

Comment: The ToCharArray uses unsafe code and pointers so I believe it's expense is just copying the string which for small strings. It depends how many operations you are doing on the string as it can be easier to work with but yes I agree for a single operation it is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this method...

```
String test = "ello World";
test = $"H{test}";
```